# breakpad 32-bit build fails on a 64-bit Linux system

Tags: linux, x86-64, google-breakpad

I am trying to build 32-bit breakpad on a 64-bit Linux system but I am getting the build error. I did the following as explained [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/).

> ./configure CXXFLAGS=-m32 CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32
>
> make

In make, I am getting the following error:

> src/common/stabs_reader.cc: In member function ‘bool google_breakpad::StabsReader::Process()’:
>
> src/common/stabs_reader.cc:98:35: error: ‘N_UNDF’ was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
>  } else if (iterator_->type == N_UNDF && unitized_) {
>                                ^
> ```
>
> Makefile:4678: recipe for target 'src/common/stabs_reader.o' failed
>
> make: *** [src/common/stabs_reader.o] Error 1

Then I looked into the `./configure` output and saw that it could be the problem with `a.out.h` because of the following output:

> checking a.out.h usability... no
>
> checking a.out.h presence... no
>
> checking for a.out.h... no

Anyone else face this problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: sounds like you're missing the linux kernel headers. On my machine they're supplied by the package `linux-libc-dev`

Comment: even with that, it doesn't build, complaining about: `src/client/linux/crash_generation/crash_generation_client.cc:40:51: fatal error: third_party/lss/linux_syscall_support.h: No such file or directory` - that file is not in the checked out source

Comment: @Petesh linux-libc-dev is already installed on my system. I am able to build 64 bit breakpad.

Comment: I have an `a.out.h`, I don't have a `linux_syscall_support.h`. I can't build breakpad on my system for a reason other than you have. Without knowing what linux version/gcc version/package version you have; we're at a standstill here.

Comment: @Petesh How did you downloaded the breakpad? Have you used `fetch breakpad` command? Or directly cloned it. There is a problem if you directly clone it. First, download google `dept_tools`. And then run `fetch breakpad`. Check the instructions here at the bottom of the page. https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/

Comment: The documentation seems to imply that I didn't need to do that; of course, annoyingly it magically works because the directory in question isn't what you check out. Still doesn't build; however the file is `<linux/a.out.h>`, so simply reference that file in the .cc file, and ensure you configure using: `env ac_cv_header_a_out_h=yes CXXFLAGS=-m32 CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32  ./configure` - I can't find `a.out.h` in `/usr/include`

Comment: I submitted a patch for breakpad to address this - it does seem to be a breakdown in the 32bit support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the 32bit breakpad build.

I've submitted a patch to the project; in the interim, you can simply edit `src/common/stabs_reader.h` and replace:

```
#include <a.out.h>
```

with

```
#include <linux/a.out.h>
```

and configuring with:

```
env ac_cv_header_a_out_h=yes CXXFLAGS=-m32 CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
```